# Problema agregar formulario en scroll PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qmainwindow

Buenas estoy creando una app sencilla, la cual tiene un boton que al darle click me muestra otra ventana con area scroll, mi problema es que en esta area scroll quiero agregar un formulario,y al intentar agregarlo de varias formas el programa se cierra al tratar de abrir la ventana con area scroll. Dejo codigo, he realizado distintas pruebas y no he logrado que funcione, si dejan en comentario desde la parte donde defino el formulario (layout) hasta donde se declara "self.vbox.addLayout(layout)", la app funciona, y muestra el area scroll vacio. Ayuda por favor.

```
class PrinWindow(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.w = None  # No external window yet.
    self.btn1 = QPushButton("Programación", self)
    self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.show_new_window1)
    self.btn1.move(10, 10)
    self.btn1.resize(150, 40)
    self.resize(400, 300)
    self.setWindowTitle('Programa Operativo Anual (POA)')


def show_new_window1(self, checked):
    if self.w is None:
        self.w = MainWindow1()
    self.w.show()


class MainWindow1(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
    self.scroll = QScrollArea()             # Scroll Area which contains the widgets, set as the centralWidget
    self.widget = QWidget()                 # Widget that contains the collection of Vertical Box
    self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()


    # Scroll Area Properties
    self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
    self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
    self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)

    self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)

    self.setGeometry(800, 400, 600, 600)
    self.setWindowTitle('Programación')
    self.show()




    layout = QFormLayout()

    self.director = QLineEdit()
    self.jefe = QLineEdit()
    self.DG = QLineEdit()
    self.jefatura = QLineEdit()
    self.T1 = QLineEdit()
    self.T2 = QLineEdit()
    self.T3 = QLineEdit()
    self.T4 = QLineEdit()

    self.generate_btn = QPushButton("Crear PDF")
    self.generate_btn.pressed.connect(self.generate)

    layout.addRow("Nombre del Director", self.director)
    layout.addRow("Dirección", self.DG)
    layout.addRow("Nombre Jefe de Proyecto", self.jefe)
    layout.addRow("Jefatura", self.jefatura)
    layout.addRow("Meta primer trimestre", self.T1)
    layout.addRow("Meta segundo trimestre", self.T2)
    layout.addRow("Meta tercer trimestre", self.T3)
    layout.addRow("Meta cuarto trimestre", self.T4)

    self.vbox.addLayout(layout)

    self.widget.setLayout(self.vbox)




    return

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = PrinWindow()
w.show()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si te entendí bien, pero prueba esto:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow1(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
#        self.setGeometry(800, 400, 600, 600)
        self.resize(600, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Programación')
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()                                 # +
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)                                # + 
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)                  # + 
        
        self.initUI()
        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scroll)                                       # +

        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Add form_widget", self)                   # +
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.form_widget)                        # +   
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)                                   # +

    def initUI(self):
        # Scroll Area which contains the widgets, set as the centralWidget
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()      
        # Widget that contains the collection of Vertical Box
        self.widget = QWidget()          
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)

        # Scroll Area Properties
# ???        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
# ?        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)

#        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)
# ???        self.show()

    def form_widget(self):                                                     # +
        groupBox = QGroupBox()                                                 # +
        layout = QFormLayout(groupBox)                                         # + groupBox

        self.director = QLineEdit()
        self.jefe = QLineEdit()
        self.DG = QLineEdit()
        self.jefatura = QLineEdit()
        self.T1 = QLineEdit()
        self.T2 = QLineEdit()
        self.T3 = QLineEdit()
        self.T4 = QLineEdit()

        self.generate_btn = QPushButton("Crear PDF")                  # ?
# ???        self.generate_btn.pressed.connect(self.generate)         # ??? self.generate

        layout.addRow("Nombre del Director", self.director)
        layout.addRow("Dirección", self.DG)
        layout.addRow("Nombre Jefe de Proyecto", self.jefe)
        layout.addRow("Jefatura", self.jefatura)
        layout.addRow("Meta primer trimestre", self.T1)
        layout.addRow("Meta segundo trimestre", self.T2)
        layout.addRow("Meta tercer trimestre", self.T3)
        layout.addRow("Meta cuarto trimestre", self.T4)

#-        self.vbox.addLayout(layout)
        self.vbox.addWidget(groupBox)                                                    # +
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.generate_btn, alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom) # +
        self.vbox.addStretch(1)                                                          # +

#        self.widget.setLayout(self.vbox)
# ???        return
  
  
class PrinWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Programa Operativo Anual (POA)')
        self.resize(400, 300)
        
#        self.w = None 
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()                                 # +
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)                                # +      
        
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Programación", self)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.show_new_window1)
#        self.btn1.move(10, 10)
        self.btn1.setFixedSize(150, 40)
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)                  # + 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn1, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
        
        self.mainWindow_1 = MainWindow1(self)

    def show_new_window1(self):                       # ? , checked):
#-        if self.w is None:
#-            self.w = MainWindow1()
        self.mainWindow_1.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = PrinWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]